# Is it possible to rotate a View in Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator

I have a View with elements in it (Labels, etc) that I'd like to rotate.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [transform](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-transform) property to apply a [2DMatrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.2DMatrix) to the view:

```
var v = Ti.UI.createView({
 transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(90)
});
```